# How to convert duration (00:15:00, 15 minutes) to fractional hours (0.25, 1/4 hour)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

This should be pretty simple for someone.
I need to convert intervals like 00:15:00 (15 minutes) or 01:45:00 (1 hours and 45 minutes) to .25 (1/4 hour or 15 minutes) or 1.75 (for 1 hour and 45 minutes).

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM hours::decimal)/60
```

This gives me 15 for the first example which is not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: Titles should attempt to summarize the question. Otherwise there are a bunch of meaningless generic titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
testdb=# select extract(epoch from '00:15:00'::interval) / 3600;
 ?column? 
----------
     0.25
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. I am really bad at explaining. I need to convert intervals like 00:15:00 to the decimal version. So 01:45:00 would convert to 1.75. This is super easy in Excel. The column name is "Hours". Thanks.

Comment: @user45481: this appears to do what you ask for. `select extract(epoch from '01:45:00'::interval) / 3600` gives you `1.75`. Just replace `'00:15:00'` with `hours`.

Comment: I get the error 'cannot cast type interval to numeric; error while preparing parameters'

Comment: Don't do `::decimal`. Use `::interval`, exactly as shown in the answer.